# How can I connect to DocumentDB in my local PC with python?

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongoengine, aws-documentdb

I'm using **AWS DocumentDB service without TLS.**
So, I can connect to DocumentDB without pem key.

Obviously I have easy access to DocumentDB from EC2, but I can't access it via Python code from my local PC.

Here is my python code. (I'm using `mongoengine` pip module.)

```py
 connect(
        os.getenv('MONGO_NAME'),
        username=os.getenv('MONGO_USER'),
        password=os.getenv('MONGO_PASSWORD'),
        host=os.getenv('MONGO_HOST'),
        port=int(os.getenv('MONGO_PORT', 27017))
    )
```

Since EC2 and DocumentDB are on the same VPC, the above code runs very well in EC2.
However, **I need to be able to access DocumentDB in the same way from my local PC for testing.**

Obviously, the environment variable is set well on my local PC.

Is there a way to access DocumentDB from a local PC using mongoengine as above?
It is okay to require TLS settings.

I'd appreciate it if you could answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can establish an SSH tunnel with the EC2 instance from your local PC, then you should be able to connect.
See the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-from-outside-a-vpc.html).
You'll have to change the MONGO_HOST variable on your local PC to localhost.